# Se borraron los controles de Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio

espero puedan resolver mi problema. Estaba modificando el código de los botones de un Form en Visual Studio 2019 y al cambiar al modo diseño me apareció el mensaje de que tenía error en el código y no se podía mostrar el diseño, entonces le dí en Omitir y continuar y se borraron todos los botones, labels y tablas que tenía, se pueden recuperar o tendría que volver a hacer todo el diseño desde 0?? De antemano gracias

Comment: Creo que no puedes recuperar  esa interfaz, te recomiendo que no modifiques los controles preestablecidos por vs ya que omitir significa que el reparara los errores formateando tu código por el correcto y muchas veces se pierde todo tu proyecto, te aconsejo que realices copias de seguridad a menudo.

Comment: Cuando eso te suceda, no le pongas omitir ya que no se puede volver hacia atrás. Así que, vas a tener que re-hacer tu interfaz

Answer (score 0):

Es fácil solucionarlo, solo tienes que ir a tu explorador de soluciones:

- Expandir tu objeto formulario, así:

[image: Lista de Archivos]

Una vez que lo tengas expandido el objeto Formulario haz doble clic en el archivo que contenga `*.Designer.cs` en mi caso es `Form1.Designer.cs`.

Debes ingresar ahí, para que Visual Studio te muestre el error y corrígelo.

Normalmente lo muestra con una línea roja ondulada, claro eso dependiendo del tipo de error que tengas

[image: Error Visual Studio]

Una vez corregido vuelves a abrir tu formulario archivo que contiene la extensión `.cs` en mi ejemplo sería `Form1.cs` y ya te debería mostrar los componentes del formulario correctamente.